# how to embed javascript code in smartys template

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

I have to include this 
http://rajendar-codinghints.blogspot.in/2012/06/add-dropdown-country-state-list-to-html.html
into my smarty's template file i.e header.tpl

Required js file is present with correct path.

Whole thing is working fine in simple html file but not in smarty
please help.

Comment: well how can i check version of my smartys project as i have ftp details is there any version file present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your Javascript code into `{literal}` tags

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  Your javascript code
// -->
</script>
{/literal}
```

See [docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal) for more details

Comment: can these select fields be also embedded under javascript code..?

Comment: It will wrap all your js code. that means anything you have implemented in Javasctipt, will be embedded within these tags.

Comment: Select Country:

<select onchange="print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country" name = "country"></select> <br />

City/District/State:

<select name ="state" id = "state"></select>

<script language="javascript"<print_country("country");</script>                  

how should i enter these fields in form of my smartys template